# Cumulative vs marginal probability of default

Tags: risk, default-probability

I understood the cumulative (aka unconditional) probability of default to be the probability of defaulting in a given period eg: between years 1 and 5. Further $\pi_{cumulative} = 1-e^{-\lambda*t}$ where lambda is a hazard rate.

I understood the marginal (aka conditional) probability of default to be the probability of defaulting at time $T$ given survival up to that point. Further $\pi_{marginal} = \lambda e^{-\lambda*t}$ where lambda is a hazard rate.

Attempting to solve the following problem, I came up with a close but off value.

*Problem*

> 1 year hazard rate = 0.1. What is the probability of surviving in the
>   first year followed by defaulting in the second?

My solution was to calculate the marginal probability of default 
= $0.1\lambda e^{0.1*2}$ = 8.19%

But the given answer was 8.61% arrived at by:

1 year cumulative (also called unconditional) PD = 1 - e^(- hazard*time) = 9.516%

2 year cumulative (also called unconditional) PD = 1 - e^(- hazard*time) = 18.127%

solution - 18.127% - 9.516% = 8.611%

***Is my approach incorrect or merely an approximation?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question sounds like a conditional probability problem. However, note that, for conditional probability, people will generally say **if survived to** or **conditional on**. Here it says that **survived in year one** and (i.e., followed by) **will default in year two**. Then we should not treat this as a conditional or marginal probability.

Based on the above understanding, the probability can be computed as follows:
\begin{align*}
P(\tau >1 \ and \ \tau \le 2) &= P(1 < \tau \le 2)\\
&=P\big((\tau \le 2) \setminus(\tau \le 1) \big)\\
&=P(\tau \le 2) - P(\tau \le 1)\\
&= \big(1- e^{-2\lambda}\big) - \big(1- e^{-\lambda}\big)\\
&= 18.127\,\% - 9.516\,\% \\
&= 8.611\,\%.
\end{align*}
Here, $\tau$ is the default time.

Comment: Interesting observation. So "survived in year 1 and defaulted in year 2" is not the same as "survived to year 2"? If so, is it because the default, in this scenario, is not necessarily at the end of year 2?

Comment: No, defaulted in year 2 does not mean to survive to year 2; it means that default happens some time from year 1 to year 2.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused now. If we say a credit "defaulted in year 2", that doesn't mean that it survived from the start of year 1 up to the point sometime before the start of year 3 when it defaulted but that it defaulted some point between the start of year 1 and before the start of year 3?

Comment: "defaulted in year 2" means that the default happens at a time $t$, where $1<t \le 2$. Here, first year refers to the time interval $[0, 1]$, while the second year refers to the time interval $[1, 2]$.

Comment: Good to know. I didn't get that before though I must admit it's counter intuitive. Thanks for your help. I'm going to leave the question open for another day just to see if I can get additional feedback that is useful.

Comment: (Possible) Moment of clarity here. Are you saying that the statement defaulted in year 2 doesn't guarantee a default didn't happen already and at some point ?

Comment: No, it didn't say anything that might happened already, that is, it  doesn't guarantee a default didn't happen already at some point.

Comment: "it doesn't guarantee a default didn't happen already at some point." - Great, is that the reason why "defaulted in year 2" is interpreted as he default happens at a time t, where 1< t ≤ 2 ?

Comment: Yes, That is correct. That is why the probability is given by $P(1 < \tau \le 2)$.

Comment: @Gordon, I am trying to calculate the Quarterly Marginal PD. My Question is When we have Quarterly PD, Is it correct to calculate the Survival rate as (1-Quarterly PiT PD)^(1/4) or Just (1-Quarterly PiT PD). In this example, I have calculated the Survival Rate as (1-Quarterly PiT PD)^(1/4). More detail has been given here. https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/67759/12108